# Is it possible to create a Java UDP Socket to listen on all addresses?

Tags: java, networking

I would like to have a single DatagramSocket to listen for both unicast and broadcast messages.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Broadcasting is, by definition, a *transmission* function.

If your UDP socket is listening on a particular port and bound to `INADDR_ANY` (aka 0.0.0.0) then it'll receive all packets sent to that port, regardless of whether they were sent to the local machine's specific IP addresses (i.e. unicast), or to the local subnet's broadcast address.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you set the address to 0.0.0.0, it'll do the work.